# How to add a build step after packageApplication

Tags: android-gradle-plugin

How to add a build step after packageApplication and make sure xxx-debug-unalined.apk has been generated?

I use packageApplication.doLast, it works ok on windows, but fail on linux, because xxx-debug-unaligned.apk not exist.

Any help would be appreciated!

See also: [How to support osgi in android gradle plugin environment?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31497091/how-to-support-osgi-in-android-gradle-plugin-enviroment)

Answer (score 0):

I fixed this issue.

It failed on linux,because updateZipFileEntry use a temp file in /tmp file system, then rename it to another file, the renameTo method ran failed,return false.

because it can not rename file in /tmp filesystem. change it to the output dir, it works ok.